# How to sync computers

Tags: synchronization, kubuntu

I would like to have my desktop and my laptop synced i.e all programs and files should be at both places. Generally only one of the devices are active at any given time. It would be nice to be able to increase this number to cover other computers/phones.

I've read these, [What is a good tool to sync two computers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41258/what-is-a-good-tool-to-sync-two-computers) and here [Sync Linux between two computers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114816/sync-linux-between-two-computers)

As far as I understand it is not desirable to sync everything since the hardware differs. So if I 'just' sync some directory/directories are there

- any settings to set
- any particular location I should store files/install applications in
- any special things to avoid
- any particular behavior/best practices I should follow

to get the seamless experience I'm looking for?

### Secondary problem

In the best of worlds I would also like to send encrypted backups to 3rd party (Amazon or Azure for example) the same way but I'm not sure if that is recommended/feasible.

### Other notes

Neither of the two computers(the desktop and laptop) have Kubuntu installed yet.

Answer (score 1):

There was once a [Ubuntu One](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne) service that did exactly that but it is gone. You can use something like [Syncthing](https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing) and basically have a deamon rsyncing your files but this only covers what is in your home directory ie installed programs not covered.

What I do suggest is have the folders you need to sync in google or dropbox. Assuming you need the systems to be synced you can use something like puppet or any other automation tool but Imho it is too much work, As you will notice upon using linux it is quite easy to install programs with a package manager so you don't need to care so much about keeping the systems synced as long you don't fiddle with the packages and keep the machines in the same distro/release.

Comment: True, the things I thought of was configs for different applications and the configs/settings for in the OS that would be nice to have synced as well of cli shortcuts and macros